# selecting rows based on multiindex comparison

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30,40], index=[[1,1,2,2],[1,4,3,2]])
df.index.names=['a','b']
```

I would like to keep the rows in which index `a` equals index `b`:

```
      0
1 1  10
2 2  40
```

I thought maybe a `lambda` could work in this case

```
df.index[lambda x: x[0]==x[1]]
```

but it doesn't. How could I get the result above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_level_values` will work for this

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0)==df.index.get_level_values(1)]
Out[455]: 
      0
a b    
1 1  10
2 2  40
```

To fix your code

```
df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0]==x[1])]
Out[457]: 
      0
a b    
1 1  10
2 2  40
```

Answer (score 3):

May be something like below, where you can check if length of each multiindex set is 1:

```
df[df.index.map(lambda x: len(set(x)))==1]
```

---

```
      0
a b    
1 1  10
2 2  40
```